# Is Steiner ellipse defining a unique triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

[Steiner ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_ellipse) is a unique ellipse that touches the triangle at its vertices and whose centre is the triangle's centroid.

Similar is the case for the [Steiner inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse). However, this one seems to be
uniquely linked to the Steiner ellipse, i.e. it carries no additional info.

So my question is whether these Steiner ellipses define a unique triangle?
It seems to me that I still have an extra degree of freedom to fix the triangle.
What is this degree of freedom once I have fixed the Steiner ellipse?

In other words, once I have a Steiner ellipse how can I parametrised all
triangles associated with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different congruent equilateral triangles with the same centroid clearly have the same Steiner circumellipse and inellipse

This will then be true in every other case too: start with a triangle and its Steiner ellipses, affine transform the ellipses to circles (the triangle becoming equilateral), rotate the triangle, and then undo the transformation to recover the original ellipses: you will have a new triangle with the original Steiner ellipses

So perhaps you could parametrise by the orientation of the transformed equilateral triangle or some function of this

Comment: Ok, I see. So, I guess I can alternatively think of it as transforming the fixed equilateral triangle in different directions until I reach the ellipses with the same parameters as my original Steiner ellipse.  The additional parameter is then this direction of stretching. Which seems to be some angle $\phi$ which is in range of a third of $2\pi$...

Answer (score 3):

In fact, this is related to a classical issue, called "Poncelet porism" or "Poncelet closure theorem" (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%27s_closure_theorem)). This theorem asserts that if 2 ellipses included one in the other have a triangle inscribed in one and circumscribed to the other, one can build an infinity of such triangles; more precisely, any point taken on the exterior ellipse can be a vertex of such a triangle.

This theorem can be generalized in two different ways: to other conic curves, and to any $n$-sided polygon.

Take a look at [this presentation](http://sodwana.uni-ak.ac.at/geom/mitarbeiter/odehnal/talk/porisms.pdf) for a very enlarged point of view... and nice graphics.

For a connection between this theorem and another famous one, Pascal's theorem, under the condition to be a little familiar with projective geometry, see [this publication](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/poncelet.pdf).

Comment: I just added two references.